# How can I preserve the user login session with AWS Cognito without using amplify in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-cognito, storage, refresh-token

I am building an app with flutter. I am trying to keep user logged in forever, even when they close their app, except they click on the logout button. I am currently using AWS Cognito for authentication, though I am not using Amplify with it.

The issue I am having now is that the user token is always null when they close the app and open it back. It logs them in automatically but does not get their token.

I am using get storage to store their login session but I guess it is not saving the idtoken or refreshing the idtoken when they close the app and log in back. How can I sort this please

I am using provider as my state management to store their login session.
Here it is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class AuthStateProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final storage = GetStorage();
  bool get isLoggedIn => storage.read('isLoggedIn') ?? false;

  Future<void> setLoggedIn(bool isLoggedIn) async {
    await storage.write('isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await storage.write('isLoggedIn', false);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I also have a getIdToken method where I am storing, refreshing and getting the current user token.
Here it is

```
Future<String> getCurrentIdToken() async {
    final storedIdToken = await AuthStateProvider().storage.read('idToken');
    final newStoredIdToken = storedIdToken.toString();

    bool isTokenValid(String token) {
      Map<String, dynamic> payload = JwtDecoder.decode(token);
      DateTime exp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(payload['exp'] * 1000);
      return exp.isAfter(DateTime.now());
    }

    Future<void> attemptTokenRefresh() async {
      final user = await userPool.getCurrentUser();
      final session = await user?.getSession();
      if (session != null && session.isValid()) {
        try {
          final newSession = session.refreshToken;
          final newIdToken = newSession?.getToken();
          final newIdTokenPayload = JwtDecoder.decode(newIdToken!);
          await AuthStateProvider().storage.write('idToken', newIdTokenPayload);
        } catch (e) {
          throw Exception('Refresh failed $e');
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Unable to refresh: Current session is not valid');
      }
    }

    if (newStoredIdToken.isNotEmpty) {
      if (isTokenValid(newStoredIdToken)) {
        return newStoredIdToken;
      } else {
        try {
          await attemptTokenRefresh();
          return AuthStateProvider().storage.read('idToken');
        } catch (e) {
          throw Exception('Unable to get current user id token');
        }
      }
    }

    final token = await userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (token != null && await token.getSession() != null) {
      final currentSession = token.getSignInUserSession();
      if (currentSession != null) {
        final idToken = currentSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        print('Retrieved ID Token: $idToken');
      } else {}
    } else {
      print('Error: Token or Session was null');
    }
    throw Exception('Unable to get current user id token');
  }

  // Get a User
  Future<CognitoUser?> getCurrentUser() async {
    final cognitoUser = await userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser != null && await cognitoUser.getSession() != null) {
      return cognitoUser;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Also this is my login method.

```
Future<void> signIn(LoginData data, BuildContext context) async {
    final authenticationDetails = AuthenticationDetails(
      username: data.email,
      password: data.password,
    );

    final user = CognitoUser(data.email, userPool);

    try {
      final authResult = await user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails);
      if (authResult?.accessToken != null) {
        final idToken = authResult?.accessToken;
        await AuthStateProvider().storage.write('idToken', idToken);
        await AuthStateProvider().setLoggedIn(true);
      }
    } on CognitoUserNewPasswordRequiredException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Password reset required: $e.'),
        ),
      );
    } on CognitoUserConfirmationNecessaryException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Account not confirmed. Check your email $e.'),
        ),
      );
    } on CognitoUserMfaRequiredException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error: Multi-Factor Authentication Required $e.'),
        ),
      );
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Network Error, please check your connection. $e'),
        ),
      );
    } on CognitoClientException catch (e) {
      if (e.message != null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(e.message!)),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Authentication error. Please try again'),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Unhandled Authentication Error'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Please I will be glad to get this help as soon as I can. Thank you

Comment: I still need help with this guys. Thank you